# Compiler keeps on repeating a print statement - C Programming Language

Tags: c, printing, repeat

Pseudo Code ->

```
idealMarks is an integer with value 80
marksGained is an integer with value 50
Check if marksGained is greater than or equal to idealMarks
If marksGained is less than idealMarks print “Try Again”
Change marksGained equal to 80
If marksGained is greater than or equal to idealMarks print “You have scored well!”
```

C Code ->

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int idealMarks; int marksGained;
   for (idealMarks = 80; marksGained = 50; marksGained == idealMarks)
   {
      printf("You have scored well!");
      marksGained = 80;
   }
   printf("Try Again");
}
```

When I execute this code it keeps on repeating a print statement.

I use the following website to execute my code - https://www.onlinegdb.com

[image: Error Image]

Comment: you have build an endless for loop.

Comment: Your `for` loop is pretty messed up.  You have a second initialization place of the exit test, an exit test in place of the increment, and no increment.  So of course it's an infinite loop.  You want `for (init; test; increment)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is an endless loop:

```
for (idealMarks = 80; marksGained = 50; marksGained == idealMarks)
```

`marksGained = 50` is always true.

```
int idealMarks = 80;
for( int marksGained = 50; marksGained < idealMarks;)
```

Is what you want

***Edit***: Also your print statements are switched, try should be inside the loop.

See [sample](https://onlinegdb.com/HJ_ecLDI8)

Comment: Now it works but I still don’t understand what went wrong. I changed the value of marksGained to 80. So when the loop restarts shouldn’t the value change to 80.

Comment: There is no check in your for loop. The check is the second statement and it is an assignment - which is always true when the assigned value is greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

This is because inside **for loop** you are assigning the value to `marksGained = 50` , it should be a conditional statement `marksGained == 50`.

Answer (score 0):

The format of a `for` statement is:

```
for (A; B; C)
    D
```

In this:

- `A` is executed first. It is normally used to set up the initial state for the loop.
- `B` is evaluated before each iteration to test whether to continue the loop (if `B` evaluates to “true” or non-zero) or exit (if `B` evaluates to “false” or zero).
- `C` is evaluated after each iteration. It is normally used to adjust the state between in a clear way corresponding to the iterations of the loop.
- `D` is a statement (often a compound statement `{ … }`) to be iterated.

In your `for` loop, you have `marksGained = 50` in place of `B`. That is an assignment expression; it puts `50` in `marksGained`. An assignment expression has a value; it is the value stored in the left operand. So this `B` always has value `50`. That is non-zero, so the `for` loop always continues.

You have `marksGained == idealMarks` in place of `C`. That is a comparison. It evaluates to “true” (1) if the two operands are equal and to “false” (0) otherwise. It has no other effect. The value of the expression in the place of `C` is not used. So this code has no effect on your program.

It is not clear what you intended to write. I suggest you write writing using just `if` statements and possibly a `do` or `while` statement instead of `for` statement at first. If you get the program working with those statements, then you can try converting the `do` or `while` statement into `for` statement.